# want to create a redux form(in a modal) which will performs of post request to a any given database

Tags: reactjs, database, redux, react-redux, state

> a react beginner
> want to create a redux form(in a modal) which will performs of post request to a any given database > this is how the modal looks
> [image]
> youll see that ive defined a separate state for each and every input, slider and switch relating which i was confused so as how to call them
> can someone please check this out and give a possible solution. Thankyou

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import { Form, Modal, Button, Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import './Tasks.css'
import { Slider, Switch, FormControlLabel, TextField, makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add'
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
```

> this is where ive defined styles for some of the components

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=> ({
    margin: {
        margin:theme.spacing(1)
    },
    textField: {
        width: '40ch',
    }
}))

const BlueSwitch = withStyles({
    switchBase: {
      color: "#29b6f6",
      '&$checked': {
        color: "#29b6f6",
      },
      '&$checked + $track': {
        backgroundColor: "#29b6f6",
      },
    },
    checked: {},
    track: {},
  })(Switch);
  
const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiSlider: {
        thumb: {
          color: "#29b6f6"
        },
        track: {
          color: "#29b6f6"
        },
        rail: {
          color: "black"
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

> styles ended

> validate function, not able to determine whether its working or not

```
  const validate = values => {
    const errors = {}
    const requiredFields = [ 'email', 'recoverymail', 'password', 'securityans' ]
    requiredFields.forEach(field => {
      if (!values[ field ]) {
        errors[ field ] = 'Required'
      }
    })
    if (values.email && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
      errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
    }
    return errors
  }


const Tasks = (props) => {
const { handleSubmit } = props

const classes = useStyles();

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
```

> ive defined this particular state for the slider but thought just by calling the values like  {runtime_min, runtime_max, sleeptime_min, sleeptime_max } in the value props of each of the sliders, but im not sure now nor i know any other way of defining its state

```
const [{runtime_min, runtime_max, sleeptime_min, sleeptime_max }, setValue] = React.useState(30);
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue)
}

const [security, setState] = React.useState({
  email: '',
  recoverymail: '',
  passowrd: '',
  securityans:'',
  runtime_min: '',
  runtime_max: '',
  sleeptime_min: '',
  sleeptime_max: ''
});

const updateInfo = (event, inputValue ) => {
  let inputField = event.target.name;
  //let inputValue = event.target.value;
  if( inputField === 'email'){
      setState({ email: inputValue })
  }
  else if( inputField === 'recoverymail'){
      setState({ email: inputValue })
  }
  else if( inputField === 'password'){
      setState({ password: inputValue })
  }
  else if( inputField === 'securityans'){
      setState({ securityans: inputValue })
  }
  else if( inputField === 'runtime_min'){
      setState({ runtime_min: inputValue })
  }
  else if( inputField === 'runtime_max'){
      setState({ runtime_max: inputValue })
  }
  else if( inputField === 'sleeptime_min'){
      setState({ sleeptime_min: inputValue })
  }
  else if( inputField === 'sleeptime_max'){
      setState({ sleeptime_max: inputValue })
  }
}
```

> on click of the create task button given below itll call this function and post all the given details

```
const create_task =(e)=>{
  let{ email, recoverymail, passowrd, securityans, runtime_min, runtime_max, sleeptime_min, sleeptime_max } = this.state;
  fetch('db_name', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content=Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          email : email,
          recoverymail : recoverymail,
          passowrd : passowrd,
          securityans : securityans,
          runtime_min : runtime_min,
          runtime_max : runtime_max,
          sleeptime_min : sleeptime_min,
          sleeptime_max: sleeptime_max                   
      })
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      window.alert(data)
  })
};
const [state, setStatei] = React.useState({
  checkedA: true,
  checkedB: true,
  checkedC: true,
  checkedD: true,
  checkedE:  true
});

const handleChangei = (event) => {
setStatei({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
};


  const renderTextField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error, invalid }, ...custom }) => (
    <TextField hintText={label}
    id="outlined-basic"
    variant="outlined"  
    label={label}
    placeholder={label}
    error={touched && invalid}
    helperText={touched && error}
      input={security.state}
      {...custom}
    />
  )

  
    return(
                    <Button className="b1" onClick={handleShow}>+ Create Task</Button>          
                    <Container>
                        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <Modal.Header className="modal-head" closeButton>
                            <Modal.Title> Create Task</Modal.Title>
                            </Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Body className="modal-body" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            
                            <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <Field  className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}  component={renderTextField} placeholder="Email" onChange={updateInfo} name="email" value={security.email}/>
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Field  className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)} component={renderTextField}  placeholder="Recovery Email" onChange={updateInfo} name="recoverymail" value={security.recoverymail}/>
                            </Col>
                            </Row>
                            <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <Field  className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)} component={renderTextField} placeholder="Password" onChange={updateInfo} name="passowrd" value={security.passowrd}/>
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Field className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)} component={renderTextField} placeholder="Security Answer" onChange={updateInfo} name="securityans" value={security.securityans}/>
                            </Col>
                            </Row>
                            <>
                            <Container class="set-ci">
                            <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <text className="text-ci">Run Time</text> <b> Minimum</b>
                                <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}> 
                                    <Slider 
                                    value={runtime_min} 
                                    onChange={handleChange} 
                                    aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always" 
                                    step={10}
                                    valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                                    />
                                </ThemeProvider>
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                            <text className="text-ci">Run Time </text> <b> Maximum</b>
                                <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}> 
                                    <Slider 
                                    value={runtime_max} 
                                    onChange={handleChange} 
                                    aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always" 
                                    step={10}
                                    valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                                    />
                                </ThemeProvider>
                            </Col>

                            </Row>
                            <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <text className="text-ci">Sleep Time </text> <b> Minimum</b>
                                <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}> 
                                <Slider 
                                value={sleeptime_min} 
                                onChange={handleChange} 
                                aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always" 
                                step={10}
                                valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                                />
                                </ThemeProvider>
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <text className="text-ci">Sleep Time </text> <b> Maximum</b>
                                <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}> 
                                <Slider 
                                value={sleeptime_max} 
                                onChange={handleChange} 
                                aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always" 
                                step={10}
                                valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                                />
                                </ThemeProvider>
                            </Col>
                            </Row>
                            </Container>
                            </>
                            <Row className="foot-row">
                            <Col>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    <FormControlLabel
                                        className="set-fcl"
                                        control=
                                        {
                                            <BlueSwitch
                                            checked={state.checkedA}
                                            onChange={handleChangei}
                                            name="checkedA"
                                        />
                                        }
                                        label="Youtube"
                                    />
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                    <FormControlLabel
                                        className="set-fcl"
                                        control=
                                        {
                                            <BlueSwitch
                                            checked={state.checkedB}
                                            onChange={handleChangei}
                                            name="checkedB"
                                        />
                                        }
                                        label="Shopping"
                                    />
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    <FormControlLabel
                                        className="set-fcl"
                                        control=
                                        {
                                            <BlueSwitch
                                            checked={state.checkedC}
                                            onChange={handleChangei}
                                            name="checkedC"
                                        />
                                        }
                                        label="Images"
                                    />
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                    <FormControlLabel
                                    className="set-fcl"
                                        control=
                                        {
                                            <BlueSwitch
                                            checked={state.checkedD}
                                            onChange={handleChangei}
                                            name="checkedD"
                                            />
                                        }
                                        label="Search"
                                    />
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    <Form>
                                    <FormControlLabel
                                        className="set-fcl"
                                        control=
                                        {
                                            <BlueSwitch
                                            checked={state.checkedE}
                                            onChange={handleChangei}
                                            name="checkedE"
                                        />
                                        }
                                        label="News"
                                    />
                                    </Form>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col className="generate-col">    
                                        <Button className="generate" onClick={create_task} type="submit" > <AddIcon/> Create Task </Button> 
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Col>
                            </Row>
                            
                            </Modal.Body>
                        </Modal>
                    </Container>
    );
}
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'simple',
    validate
    })(Tasks)
```

> onclick of the create task button i get an error stating "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" which im not able to debug
> [image: error]

Comment: Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this question too long.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this.state instead of security.

```
let { email, recoverymail, passowrd, securityans, runtime_min, runtime_max, sleeptime_min, sleeptime_max } = security;
```

Since you are using functional component and state hook, you can't access the state's value using this.state as it is only used on class based components.

I encourage you to read more on [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) as you are using some of them wrong.

Edit:
For setValue, it's better to use the security state and modify it rather than creating another. One thing to modify it is

```
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    // assign security to a new variable, we shouldn't modify states directly
    let securityData = security;
    // then modify the properties that you want
    securityData.runtimemin = 30;
    securityData.runtimemax = 30;
    // then fire up the setState hook and passing your modified object
    setState(securityData);
}
```

Comment: can you also help me out with the setValue state ive mentioned .. any scope on improvement in that?

Comment: I've added some edits, that's an example of how you handle/modify your state. You don't necessarily need to put on the handleChange function.

Comment: after changing it to security in your first reply now i get this error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name

Answer (score 0):

for my view i see that maybe you a make a mistake when you try to use destructing with "this.state" , this isn´t a class component, instead of you should only use state.

```
 let{ email, recoverymail, passowrd, securityans, runtime_min, runtime_max, sleeptime_min, sleeptime_max } = state
```

but too i see that properties doesn`t exist in the state that you call, that propertis are in security, then ...

```
let{ email, recoverymail, passowrd, securityans, runtime_min, runtime_max, sleeptime_min, sleeptime_max } = security
```